# Android webView disable Wikipedia search bar

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm building an app which using webView and loading Wikipedia's web pages. I would like to disable this part:
[image: Wikipedia search bar]

I don't know what is the best way to do this... I have thought of auto scrolling down, but then the user is able to scroll up.
Auto scrolling down is also doesn't accurate and may hide some of the value's information.

Thanks.

Comment: do you simply want to show information from wikipedia to your users ?

Comment: Yes, but I want them to be able to navigate in wikipedia, and move between the pages.

Comment: Then there is no direct way you can do it. One hack is to apply a margin top in minus value to your webview to hide the search bar. Again its not a good way to do it. If you want to show info from wikipedia, there are APIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking into Wikipedia's source code you can see that the search bar is located inside a `div` container with the class name "header-container header-chrome". You are able to remove it from the view using `JavaScripct` code and the `HTML DOM getElementsByClassName() Method`.

The following code might help you with removing the search bar from the HTML page and display the rest.

```
WebView myWebViewDisply = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebViewDisply);
myWebViewDisply.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebViewDisply.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    myWebViewDisply.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
        "document.getElementsByClassName
        ('header-container header-chrome')[0].style.display='none';" 
        +"})()");
    }
});
myWebViewDisply.loadUrl(youUrl);
```