# Issues with dropdown inside Android webview

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, webview, menu

I am just trying to make a mobile bookmark for a website with `webview`, but the mobile browser will work in hiding the menu bar (hamburger menu). It will not hide or collapse it in `webview`. It stays open, I've toggled the options commented out in the code below but nothing is working.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(" website name");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled (true);
        //mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        //mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        //mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        //mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        //mWebView.setFocusable(false);
        //mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        //mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
       // mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you able to share an example of the HTML output here or on jsfiddle, or a screenshot of what the issue is? Not sure I fully understand.

Comment: its similar to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857091/android-webview-disable-wikipedia-search-bar 
but my issue is the menu box from the top left is always down or open.
app is here - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=commonsterhunterworldwiki.fextralife.wiki.httpsmonsterhunterworld.mhwwiki&hl=en